# Using QTImage with OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, include

Ok so i was given some code and need to set it up. I am unfamiliar with c++ and the includes say:

```
#include <Qt\qimage.h>
#include <Qt\qgl.h>
#include "imageloader.h"
```

I have looked into it and there is a download on the QT-Image website, however I do not have permission on my computer (at college) to install the program.

Am I doing it wrong? or are there headers for this i can use instead? These are the only missing components left for the application (needed glut, gml and glew too)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download installation of the Qt. Even if you find headers for `qimage`, it will include headers for other parts of Qt, and you will surely need Qt libraries to link them in your application.

You could download and install it to the external hdd (or usb flash) on your home computer, and you could setup college computer's environment to search for the header files in that location.